# Why is gradle is not signing my artifacts

Tags: android, gradle, gnupg

I got a new Macbook and would like to upload a new version of my android
library by using [gradle publish plugin](https://github.com/vanniktech/gradle-maven-publish-plugin). It worked on my previous macbook  but on my new one Signing the archives are skipped.

I just run `./gradlew :library:uploadArchives`. This should include signing as well.

> ...
>
> Task :library:signArchives SKIPPED
>
> Task :library:uploadArchives
>
> ...

I have imported my public-private key `.asc` file. However, the files signature files are missing on Nexus Sonatype (although it worked on my previous macbook just fine). But now Nexus Sonatpype says that `library.aar.asc` is missing, `library-javadoc.jar.asc` is missing, `library.pom.asc` and `library-sources.jar.asc` is missing.

Any idea what I did wrong?

[image]